# Neo4j Rest Api - update property

Tags: neo4j

Anybody else has had individual properties set using rest api sometimes sometimes doesn't take into effect? It only happens sometimes. We run in a HA environment. Anybody have any ideas? We are on Neo4j 2.1.3 enterprise on CentOS

Comment: Which REST endpoint do you use?

Comment: Href properties that the rest api returns when u fetch a node...

Comment: do u think its because we don't write to a master and because we go thru the LB ?